# mysql query order by and union with concatenated strings

Tags: mysql, union

i have this query :

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(users.id, '#_#', users.nickname, '#_#', users.avatar, '#_#',
         questions.datetime,'#_#',questions.question,'#_#',0000) as summary
FROM
  `questions` join users
  on users.id = questions.id_user 
WHERE
  questions.id = 12 
UNION 
SELECT
  CONCAT(users.id, '#_#', users.nickname, '#_#', users.avatar, '#_#',
         answers.datetime,'#_#',answers.answer,'#_#',answers.id) as summary 
FROM
  answers join users
  on users.id = answers.id_user where id_question = 12
```

This query must result with one column (with concatenated data) and i need to order by the answers.datetime but i'm unable to find a solution by myself ...

some mysql guru can help me ?

Thanks :)

Comment: By the way, you can simplify these with [`CONCAT_WS('#_#',users.id,users.nickname,etc....)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

Comment: What about the `questions.datetime` for ordering?  Since the first part of the `UNION` doesn't join `answers`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT datetime,
    CONCAT(users.id,'#_#',users.nickname,'#_#',users.avatar,'#_#',questions.datetime,'#_#',questions.question,'#_#',0000) as summary 
  FROM `questions` 
  join users on users.id = questions.id_user 
  WHERE questions.id = 12 
  union 
  select datetime,
    CONCAT(users.id,'#_#',users.nickname,'#_#',users.avatar,'#_#',answers.datetime,'#_#',answers.answer,'#_#',answers.id) as summary 
  from answers 
  join users on users.id = answers.id_user where id_question = 12
) A ORDER BY datetime
```

Assuming you meant sort on `datetime`, not `answers.datetime`.